# Is it possible to download browser in iphone simulator

Tags: xcode, selenium, webdriver, simulator

I run my selenium tests across different web browsers like google chrome, firefox ie ect. These tests are being conducted in windows and Mac machine. We have requirement to run those tests in mobile browsers. I was able to run in mobile simulator safari browser successfully.

Now, I am wondering if it is possible to run those selenium tests in other browsers like opera mini but I was not able download opera mini browser in my simulator.

Can any one suggest me if it is possible to download browsers in simulators. I am using XCODE to build simulator.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

No, you can't install apps into the iOS simulator except for an app you can actually build in Xcode.

Use a real iOS device to test using different browsers.

Answer (score 29):

You could download and build the Chromium iOS browser in Xcode and run it in the iOS Simulator. It should be close to / in parity with the Chrome iOS browser, at least from a page rendering perspective (difference include things like Chrome's auto update feature, built-in PDF view, Chrome's custom print preview, etc. Mostly ancillary features to the core browsing experience.

**Chromium (iOS)** build instructions: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/ios/build_instructions.md

**Firefox (iOS)** build instructions:
https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/firefox-ios